# Overlays in KMZ not showing

Tags: overlay, kmz

The map is here, http://rockymtngreenway.org/~greenway/GoogleAPImap.html

The KMZ was created in Google Earth.

There are three images overlays on this map, and they are not appearing.

The strange thing is that the overlays appeared once, now every reload the map has the overlays missing.

Stumped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The GroundOverlays in the references KML is using a Google Earth extension `<gx:LatLonQuad>` which is not supported in Google Maps API.

List of supported KML elements in Google Earth API
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps

```
<GroundOverlay>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <Icon>
        <href>http://rockymtngreenway.org/~greenway/rockyMtnArsenalLabel9.png</href>
        <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <gx:LatLonQuad> ***
        <coordinates>
            -104.8533817983386,39.8660912769105,0 -104.7777966394869,39.8660912769105,0 -104.7777966394869,39.88672843848668,0 -104.8533817983386,39.88672843848668,0 
        </coordinates>
    </gx:LatLonQuad> ***
</GroundOverlay>
```

Try to convert your KML to standard KML 2.2 without Google Earth extensions using [LatLonBox](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#latlonbox) element.

In addition, the visibility of the ground overlays is 0 (false) so they are not visible by default.